# NSURLSession background uploading huge files

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am trying to upload a large file 2GB in the background using `NSURLSessionUploadTask`. The service uses multipart format, so in order to upload it in the background i am creating a temporary file with the Body of the request, then i am using a uploadTask to schedule the upload and when the files finishes uploading i am deleting the temporary file.

`NSURLSessionUploadTask  *uploadTask = [[self backgroundNSURLSession] uploadTaskWithRequest:uploadRequest fromFile:filePath];
[uploadTask resume];`

With files smaller then 1.4 GB the upload worked ok, but when I try to upload video files of 2 GB, the upload fails. Server is returning error message that i did not attached the file.

I am refactoring the upload component from ASIHTTP to NSURLSession if i do the upload with ASIHTTP it works even for large files.

This is how i create my NSURLSession:

```
 if ([NSURLSessionConfiguration respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:)]) {
        self.configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:appID];
    } else  {
        self.configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:appID];
    }
    self.configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
    self.configuration.discretionary = YES;
    self.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60*60;
    self.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest  = 60*60;
    backgroundSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

So the problem is only for large files, for small files the upload is performed. Has anyone else encountered the same problem?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't something simple like the timeoutIntervalForResource being far too low ?

Comment: I am not sure if this is still useful but, I changed timeIntervalForResource and forRequest to a huge value and still the same issue.

Comment: 2 years after you asked the question, that was a big time interval !!!

Answer (score 0):

According with apple developer description for property [discretionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1411552-discretionary) 
if the file is so large, the system might be waiting for a good moment like a WIFI connection.

Switch discretionary property to NO and try again. good luck!

```
self.configuration.discretionary = NO;
```

Comment: Maybe does not answer the question, You need to be sure, and give facts that support your answer

Comment: sorry! it is understood ... it my first answer

Comment: This is a old question, is not really relevant now, maybe it was a iOS SDK bug or a server bug, who knows.